# How do I combine a manipulate equation and a circle equation?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Here is my code so far:

```
p1 = 
   Manipulate[
     ParametricPlot[
       {2(n - 1)Cos[t] + 2Cos[(n - 1)t], 2(n - 1)Sin[t] - 2Sin[(n - 1)t]}, 
       {t, 0, 2 Pi}], {n, 2, 10, 1}]
p2 = ParametricPlot[{8 Cos[t], 8 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2π}]
Show[p1, p2]
```

but it just prints separate equations

Answer (score 1):

Just put them in same Manipulate. Do not use output of Manipulate inside Show.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{p1, p2},
  p2 = ParametricPlot[{8 Cos[t], 8 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
  p1 = ParametricPlot[{2 (n - 1) Cos[t] + 2 Cos[(n - 1) t], 
     2 (n - 1) Sin[t] - 2 Sin[(n - 1) t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
  Show[p2, p1]
  ],
 {n, 2, 10, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or since `p1` does not depend on `n` you can calculate it once

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{p1,t},
  p1 = ParametricPlot[{2 (n - 1) Cos[t] + 2 Cos[(n - 1) t], 
     2 (n - 1) Sin[t] - 2 Sin[(n - 1) t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
  Show[p2, p1]
  ],
 {n, 2, 10, 1},
 Initialization :> (p2 = 
    ParametricPlot[{8 Cos[t], 8 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}])
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since `ParametricPlot` can display multiple parametric curves, you could just write this simple `Manipulate` expression:

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[
    {{2 (n - 1) Cos[t] + 2 Cos[(n - 1) t], 2 (n - 1) Sin[t] - 2 Sin[(n - 1) t]},
     {8 Cos[t], 8 Sin[t]}},
    {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
  {n, 2, 10, 1}]
```

[image: demo]